# Difficulty implementing Chart widget with Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-mobile, kendo-chart, telerik-appbuilder

I'm creating a mobile app using KendoUI in the Telerik AppBuilder. I created a blank view to hold my chart and then went in to start adding the code. I cannot get the chart to appear.

These are the scripts referenced in my index.html:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="kendo/js/kendo.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="lib/progress/progress.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="dataProviders/progressDataProvider.js"></script>
```

Here is the code of my chart view:

```
<div data-role="view" data-title="Audit Tracker" data-layout="main" data-    model="app.auditTracker" data-show="app.auditTracker.onShow" data-after-show="app.auditTracker.afterShow">

    <div id="chart">
    </div>

</div>
```

And here is the code in the associated JavaScript file:

```
'use strict';

app.auditTracker = kendo.observable({
    onShow: function () {},
    afterShow: function () {}
});



(function(parent) {

        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            title: {
                text: "Audit Tracker"
            },
            series: [
                {name: "Audits Completed", data: [5,10,15,3]}
            ],
            categoryAxis: {
                categories: ["January", "February", "March", "April"]
            }
        });
})(app.auditTracker);
```

What am I doing wrong here? This seems like it should be simple!
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I did not have the correct framework files referenced in my index.html.
Here are the files that I ended up using as far as the framework goes:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="kendo.default.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>
```